# Complex number array format efficiency for common operations

Tags: matrix, format, storage, numerical, complex-numbers

Another person in my office and I got into a discussion about which complex number matrix array format is more efficient: storing the real and imaginary parts interleaved, as in

```
struct {
    double real;
    double imag;
} Complex foo[m][n];
```

or by storing the real and imaginary parts of the matrix separately:

```
struct {
    double rarray[m][n];
    double iarray[m][n];
} CArray foo;
```

On the one hand, `Complex[][]` is more of a straightforward representation of an array of complex numbers, and might be easier to work on elementwise; on the other hand, it seems that `CArray` could be more efficient in general. For example, matrix multiplication can be done using 4 matrix multiplications of the component arrays using the `CArray` format, while the `Complex[][]` format seems as though it might suffer due to interleaving between the elements (since (a+bi)*(c+di) = (ad - bc) + (ac + bd)i). Apparently, MATLAB uses the latter format: [enter link description here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f21585.html).

Are there any other sources that treat this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the age old "array of structures vs structure of arrays" question applied to complex numbers.   Like most performance questions, in general the answer is "it depends", but in this case I would put my money on the array of structures version.

The key to choosing efficient data structures for numerical computing is to keep data you're typically going to need at the same time near each other in memory.  Going out to main memory to get data is slow; you want to bring in one chunk of data at a time into cache and use all of that cache line as much as possible.  Since you're almost always going to need both the real and imaginary component of a complex number for most meaningful computations, storing them as arrays of (real,imaginary) pairs means that if you're working on the real component, the imaginary component is almost always going to be sitting there already in cache ready to be computed upon.

But it depends on access patterns.  Just because the operations I imagine are going to benefit from the array of complex numbers, doesn't mean you're imagining the same ones; others could benefit from the two-array approach.  If you had lots of operations on matricies A and B like Re(A)*Im(B) - what that would mean, I don't know, but still - then I think that one would likely be significantly faster in the CArray approach, since you wouldn't have to waste memory bandwidth by loading in data you wouldn't need (eg, Im(A) and Re(B).)

Ultimately, this is an empirical question; if you have an idea of what your mix of access patterns is, it's easy enough to test out the two approaches.  But for the patterns I can most easily envision, the first approach would win.

The fact that Matlab disagrees with me, as per your link, surprises me enough to almost make me doubt my answer.   I'm not a huge Matlab fan, but the Matlab people are smart and concerned about making numerical computation fast.  But this is one of those decisions which, once made, is incredibly hard to undo - Matlab couldn't change such a fundamental data layout now without breaking zillions of other things, of their own and third-party - and the decision was probably made decades ago when cache performance was less crucial and compatability with certain libraries probably mattered more.   I note that packages like Lapack are based on the other format, array of structures (although only implicitly -- in Fortran, complex has been a primitive data type since at least FORTRAN 66).

Comment: Another option which may be best in some languages like Java would be to use represent an NxN matrix as an Nx2N array of doubles.  That would allow a memory layout similar to the array of structures even though Java doesn't support structures types.

Comment: Funny your comment there, MATLAB just changed to the other format earlier this year -- with lots of additional data copies when necessary for compatibility with user's C/C++ code.